# Как создать список изображений находящийся в одной папке на python

Tags: python, opencv

Все мои изображения хранятся в папке с адресом C:\Users\User\images
Я хочу с ними работать, обрабатывать и так далее, передаю их в программу с помощью imread("img1.jpg")
Но так получается работать с одним изображением хранящимся в папке проекта
И я думаю создать список с этими изображениями и уже по нему "ходить"
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glob - выбор файлов по маске.

```
import glob

for name in glob.glob("C:/Users/User/images/**.jpg"):
   open(name ....
```

`**` - с подкаталогами

Comment: `import glob
import cv2

for name in glob.glob("C:/Users/User/images/**.jpg"):
   cv2.imshow("a",name)`
почему выдает ошибку? что я не так делаю?

Comment: cv2.imread(name)

Comment: все равно ошибка будто изображение не считалось

Comment: глоб файлы ищет, а не читает проверь вывод

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

images = os.listdir('C:\Users\User\images')
```